# Retrieving the file size / checksum

Tags: rest, metadata, file, size

Does SharePoint have metadata for file *size* and *checksum* via REST?

### Retrieving Metadata

I can retrieve and item's information using:

```
_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/file.ext')/ListItemAllFields
```

I can see many metadata information, including created and modified dates.  That said, I haven't seen any metadata item that shows the file's size.  Is the information available?

---

### End Goal

What I would really like is to retrieve all the metadata for all files in a specific folder, including the file size and checksum.

My current method involves downloading the file and obtaining the file size locally, which is more resource intensive than I'd like -- I'd especially like to avoid downloading large files.

Likewise, is there a checksum that could be used to compare local files to those stored in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

Make a GET request using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) It will show response in JSON format.

You can use the below rest Api to make a request.

```
/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Library Name/DocumentName.doc')/Length?@target='http://YourSiteUrl/'
```

And you should be able to see the response in JSON format like this with the Length of the file:
[image]

OR Using Ajax call and you can get the Length and convert it to Human readable format:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/LibraryName/DocumentName.doc')/Length?@target=http://YourSiteUrl/", //THE ENDPOINT
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(getFileSize(data.d.Length));

        function getFileSize(size) {
            var i = Math.floor( Math.log(size) / Math.log(1024) );
            return ( size / Math.pow(1024, i) ).toFixed(2) * 1 + ' ' + ['B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'][i];
        };

    },

    error: function(data) {
        failure(data); // Do something with the error
    }

  });
```

You can see the file size in kb in the Console log:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below rest api to get file size without downloading file...

```
<yourdomain>/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/file.ext')/Properties
```

You will get one node with below name which will return file size....

```
<d:vti_x005f_filesize m:type="Edm.Int32">1003</d:vti_x005f_filesize>
```

Not sure about checksum but I see streamhash as one of property...

```
<d:vti_x005f_streamhash>0x0294A7C818EE18894876DF25B5326D60910A24A820</d:vti_x005f_streamhash>
```

Comment: Are these properties documented anywhere?  That's a lazy question, since I haven't searched yet (but plan to).  Also, do do you know of any way to do this for multiple files in a folder?  I want to reduce HTTP requests if I can.  -- Otherwise, this is perfect and will most likely be my accepted answer once I give it a try!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work -- I was able to `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/path')/Properties`, but not for the file

Comment: But according to the MSDN, there's a "length" property, which is the file size:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileProperties

Comment: It should work for file also, I have given a try and then posted above answer xml nodes which in answer represent actual file size, what are you getting when trying ? You can direct put above in any browser and you should get xml response...

Comment: Just what I mentioned the `getFileBy.../Properties` doesn't display the *vti...filesize*, but does include a *Length*; whereas the `getFolderBy.../Properties` does have the filesize.  I don't think that's a limitation of my implementation, since the help docs seem to confirm what I'm seeing.